# Restful WCF return http 400

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a web service interface looks like

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IASchoolsWebService
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Categories?shortString={shortString}")]
        IEnumerable<string> GetCategoriesByShortString(string shortString);
}
```

and the implementation looks like

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
    public class ASchoolsWebService: IASchoolsWebService
    {

public IEnumerable<string> GetCategoriesByShortString(string shortString)
        {
// my Implementation here 

}

}
```

the web service works fine using web reference , but I want to use as RESTFULL service for further mobuke applicaitons any idea why I get 4oo if I called using browser

```
mywebservice.svc/Categories
```

I use web.conig like :

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SchoolsWebServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="SchoolsWebServiceSecureBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="ArabicEWorld.WebService.ArabicEWorldWebService" behaviorConfiguration="SchoolsWebServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint name="UnsecureEndpoint" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfig" contract="ArabicEWorld.WebService.IArabicEWorldWebService" />
    <!--<endpoint name="SecureEndpoint"
             binding="basicHttpBinding"
             bindingConfiguration="secureBasicHttpBindingConfig"
             contract="MedStreaming.Schools.Server.WebService.IMedStreamingSchoolsWebService"/>-->
  </service>
</services>
```

Answer (score 0):

Http error code 400 signifies "BadData" and commonly means you didnt send the proper parameters. In your code, you are expecting to receive a query parameter called shortString:

```
"Catagories?shortString={shortString}"
```

But you do not provide that parameter in your browser attempt:

```
mywebservice.svc/Catagories
```

If you were to instead use:

```
mywebservice.svc/Catagories?shortString=testString
```

you would be sending the proper parameter.

Comment: I have the same issue even by add parameter

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfectly with URL="http://localhost:54632/mywebservice.svc/Categories?shortString=shortString" 
 But if you are returning other type rather than 'IEnumerable < String  >' then You need to use [ServiceKnownType] in interface.. depending on what you are return from your method...

Thanks,